# Transfer money from PayPal to customers bank account with PHP

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I'm building a website where users can buy virtual money and later sell them. I have already made the system for buying the credits with PayPals [DoDirectPayment API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPDirectPayment), but im stuck at the point of paying the user when he wants to sell them.

How can i pay a user who dosn't have a [PayPal](http://paypal.com) account?

When its possible to get money from creditcard numbers, shouldn't be possible to do it the other way around?

By the way, i am using [Angelleyes](http://www.angelleye.com/) library for paypal payments, if its make any difference.

This is my first time with website payments, so i have no experience at this.

Comment: Sorry, but "first time" and "website payments" and "credit card" all put together make me very nervous...

Comment: sounds like you should be starting with good legal\accounting advise.

Comment: you should use this forum for more practical things like code.  try the discussion board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot transfer money to ones bank account but you programatically make a payment to a Paypal account using Mass Payment: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_batch-payment-overview-outside